# mod_http_upload - HTTP File Upload (XEP-0363) using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ejabberd

I want to transfer image between users in my chat application. I am using an ejabberd server for chat. As I found out, the module which could do this is `mod_http_upload` - HTTP File Upload (XEP-0363).

I am not able to figure out how to implement this. Anybody how could help me in figuring out how to do this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use this module  add configuration setting in ejabberd.yml file

```
listen:
    # add following lines in listen section
    -
      module: ejabberd_http
      port: 5443
      tls: true
      certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/example.com.pem"
      request_handlers:
        "": mod_http_upload

  access:    # add following lines in access section
    soft_upload_quota:
      all: 1000 # MiB
    hard_upload_quota:
      all: 1100 # MiB

  modules:  #add following lines in modules section 
      mod_http_upload:
      docroot: "/home/xmpp/upload"
      put_url: "http://@HOST@:5443"
```

upload file on this url (according to your setting url) `http://@HOST@:5443`  as you do in ruby on rails .For  more detail about configuration of module check this link-
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/blob/master/mod_http_upload/README.txt

after  uploading file you can send link(url) to user for downloading file.

Comment: I have done this configuration in ejabberd.yml file . Ejabberd has started after adding module . How can i check module is working fine from backend as i dont have front end ready till know. @Sunil Singh

Comment: first check module is enabled or not from  admin login of ejabberd  from web browser with  http://127.0.0.1:5280/admin. When you type put_url in new browser tab type in address bar http://127.0.0.1:5443/ it will return internal server error means module is working .(replace your ip from 127.0.0.1). you can also check it by ping the ip and port.

Comment: It is showing in admin login panel  . It is also pinging to the ip and port . When i type put_url in the browser it shows a Not Found on the left corner on the screen.

Comment: Any tool by which i can test image transfer between two user ?? And is image transfer between user stored in any table of ejabberd database as the message transfer are stored in archive ??

Comment: this module can be used for file upload only after uploading file it return upload fileurl and thumb url .if you want to store file info on database you have to manage your own .read this specification  http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html

Comment: Ok . Thank u for the information . It was really helpful . Once front end is developed then i could really transfer file between users . After that i might disturb you again if i am stuck at something .

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used https and its worked