# XEP-0363: HTTP File Upload in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ejabberd, xmppframework

Working on chat application with XMPP ejabberd server, here i am not able to get slot for image upload, this is a document (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html) for upload attachment on server

Here it is my code, my problem is after requesting with this code no any response from server nothing happen my server is working i can able to send text message, please help.

```
        let iqRequest = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "iq") as! DDXMLElement

        iqRequest.addAttribute(withName: "from", stringValue: sender.myJID.full())
        iqRequest.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: messageID!)
        iqRequest.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "get")
        iqRequest.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: "upload.hostname")

         let requestElement = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "request", uri: "urn:xmpp:http:upload") as! DDXMLElement

         let fileNameElement = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "filename") as! DDXMLElement
         fileNameElement.stringValue = "imageName.png"

         let sizeElement = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "size") as! DDXMLElement
         sizeElement.stringValue = "23456"

         requestElement.addChild(fileNameElement)
         requestElement.addChild(sizeElement)


        iqRequest.addChild(requestElement)
        sender.send(iqRequest)
```

Comment: can you help me to upload the file in objective c. provide sample code or give idea of xep - 0363.  i have so many ressarch on this but not work anything

Answer (score 2):

Have you also installed the ejabberd extension? You should refer to this question no how to setup the extension: [HTTP File Upload (XEP-0363)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578600/mod-http-upload-http-file-upload-xep-0363-using-ruby-on-rails). You check that the module is enabled from the admin panel.

However, personally I wouldn't use ejabberd to host the files. In the past I've uploaded the files to a standard Apache server and then just sent the image URL via XMPP. This has benefits because it gives you much more control over the files. For example, you could use AWS to host the files and then distribute them over a CDN.